# Why is array empty when running Android Studio?

Tags: android, xcode, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react native and firebase realtime database to store and query a list of properties. It seems that when I run the below query in XCode for iOS the array created here shows a list of the property objects. However, when I run this android studio the array is empty. Do you know what may be causing this? Can someone please help here I am very new to react native and using firebase realtime database?

I really do apologies for the poor code formatting:

```
const array = []

await db.ref(`users/`).on(`value`, snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot){
                if(userSnapshot.hasChild("properties")){
                    userSnapshot.child("properties").forEach((propertySnapshot) => {
                        array.push({
                          key: userSnapshot.key,
                          property: propertySnapshot.val(),
                          username: userSnapshot.val().username,
                          email: userSnapshot.val().email,
                          phoneNumber: (userSnapshot.val().phoneNumber != null)?userSnapshot.val().phoneNumber:null,
                          propertyName: propertySnapshot.key,
                          profile_pic: userSnapshot.val().profile_pic,
                          connectedAccount_id: (userSnapshot.val().connectedAccount_id != null)?userSnapshot.val().connectedAccount_id:null,
                          customer: (userSnapshot.val().customer != null)?userSnapshot.val().customer:null,
                        });
                    })
                }
            })
          }
        });

   await database().ref(`users/${auth().currentUser.uid}/your_location`).once(`value`, function(snap){
    ....

    Geocoder.init("******");
        
        Geocoder.from(locationPostcode)
            .then(json => {

              var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;

                global.latitude = location.lat;
                global.longtitude = location.lng;
            })
            .catch(error => console.warn(error));


         console.log("array result "+array)

    .....


     })
```

The log array shows an array of objects for iOS:
array result [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

but for android it's empty:

array result

Comment: Is this same behaviour on android device?

Comment: i'm not too sure, I don't have an android device available. However, I would think it should appear on the emulator.

Comment: Ok, Please log the response of api so you have surety that you are getting data from API and log the newProperties as well

Comment: The array I'm creating to retrieve the properties from the realtime database in Firebase is empty for android using the query above but seems to work fine for iOS.

Comment: Can anyone help here please?

Comment: Can someone please help?